# XSL: finding a node based on the content of another node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file that looks like this:

```
<container>
<bugs>
    <bug id="b1">
        <reporter>Tom</reporter>
        ...
    </bug>
    <bug id="b2">
        <reporter>Jane</reporter>
        ...
    </bug>
</bugs>
<users>
    <user>
        <userid>10</userid>
        <username>Tom</username>
    </user>
    <user>
        <userid>5</userid>
        <username>Jane</username>
    </user>
</users>
</container>
```

The endresult should be:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <bugid>b1</bugid>
        <author id="10">Tom</author>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bugid>b2</bugid>
        <author id="5">Jane</author>
    </item>
</items>
```

Problem: I can't get the comparison correct for the id lookup.

I assumed it would be like this:

```
<xsl:template match="bug">
....
    <xsl:element name="author">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="//users/user[username=reporter]/userid"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
....
</xsl:template>
```

But this returns an empty id ( id="" ).

```
<xsl:value-of select="//users/user[username='Tom']/userid"/>
```

returns 10
and

```
<xsl:value-of select="reporter"/>
```

returns Tom.

I don't see what's wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//users/user[username=reporter]/userid
```

looks for a `user` containing equal `username` and `reporter` elements. It does not search for the `reporter` in your `bug`.

You can get this to work by binding the reporter's name to a variable first:

```
<xsl:element name="author">
  <xsl:variable name="reporter" select="string(reporter)"/>
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="//users/user[username=$reporter]/userid"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: I initially tried a similar approach, but missed the string(...) cast. Thanks. It works now. AND.... turns out I had some users missing in the <users> section that were present in the <bug> section. So it was valid that they didn't return an ID. :-( BUT, I only noticed because others now produced the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kUIdByName" match="userid" use="../username"/>

 <xsl:template match="bugs">
  <items>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </items>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="bug">
  <item>
   <bugid><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></bugid>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </item>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="reporter">
  <author id="{key('kUIdByName',.)}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></author>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<container>
    <bugs>
        <bug id="b1">
            <reporter>Tom</reporter>     
        </bug>
        <bug id="b2">
            <reporter>Jane</reporter>     
        </bug>
    </bugs>
    <users>
        <user>
            <userid>10</userid>
            <username>Tom</username>
        </user>
        <user>
            <userid>5</userid>
            <username>Jane</username>
        </user>
    </users>
</container>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<items>
   <item>
      <bugid>b1</bugid>
      <author id="10">Tom</author>
   </item>
   <item>
      <bugid>b2</bugid>
      <author id="5">Jane</author>
   </item>
</items>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of **[keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key)** for the lookup.

Comment: Never used keys before, but this is very helpful in explaining how to. Thanks.

Comment: I thought I'd already done that, but it looks like I can only mark 1 answer as accepted. Therefore in writing here: I fully accept this answer as very useful.